# How to open a new window in Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, raphael, new-window

How to open a new window like "_blank" in Raphael?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the standard JavaScript method...

```
window.open('url', '_blank');
```

Raphael is a vector drawing library, so it shouldn't have an *open in new window* function.